# Jordan Identity over $char\neq2$ implies power-associativity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, jordan-algebras, nonassociative-algebras

Let $A$ be non-comutative Algebra over a field  of characteristic not 2 that satisfies $(xx)(xy)=x(y(xx))$. Can we say that $A$ is power-associative?

My attempt: I'm trying to disprove the claim for any field but only found a counterexample for characteristic 2. I do know that a Jordan Algebra is power-associative but the comutativeness seems crucial therefore I believe the answer for the above question is "no". Any example is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Schafer proved in $1955$ that any noncommutative Jordan algebra of characteristic different from $2$ is power-associative. For the proof see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2032791?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Comment: Thank you, Dietrich. A note to readers: the result is only true when the algebra is unital, for nonunital algebras there is a counterexample regardless of characteristic.